# Why is the dynamic serialization group I've created not allowing a mutation for the specified property?

Tags: serialization, graphql, api-platform.com

I've implemented a Dynamic Serialization group via Context Builder for admin users (adding admin:write). And have assigned this group to the property I want only updatable by an admin via GraphQL.

My implementation at this point is taken directly from https://api-platform.com/docs/core/graphql/#changing-the-serialization-context-dynamically

But when attempting to mutate this property I am given an error that reads `Field "roles" is not defined by type updateUserInput.`

This makes some sense to me as the schema does not contain this property since it is not in the typical `write` group. However, the documentation suggests this should be doable. If this is the case, what am I not doing correctly?

Relevant Code:

**Context Builder**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Serializer;

use ApiPlatform\Core\GraphQl\Serializer\SerializerContextBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;

/**
 * Context Builder: Experimental implementation used for constructing what resources are returned.
 */
final class AdminGroupsContextBuilder implements SerializerContextBuilderInterface {
  private $decorated;
  private $authorizationChecker;

  /**
   *
   */
  public function __construct(SerializerContextBuilderInterface $decorated, AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker) {
    $this->decorated = $decorated;
    $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
  }

  /**
   *
   */
  public function create(?string $resourceClass, string $operationName, array $resolverContext, bool $normalization): array {
    $context = $this->decorated->create($resourceClass, $operationName, $resolverContext, $normalization);
    $resourceClass = $context['resource_class'] ?? NULL;

    if (isset($context['groups']) && $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') && FALSE === $normalization) {
      $context['groups'][] = 'admin:input';
    }

    return $context;
  }

}
```

**User Entity Class property definition**

```php
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="json")
   * @Groups({"read", "admin:write"})
   */
  private $roles = [];
```

**Services Definition**

```yaml
    App\Serializer\AdminGroupsContextBuilder:
        decorates: 'api_platform.graphql.serializer.context_builder'
        arguments: [ '@App\Serializer\AdminGroupsContextBuilder.inner' ]
        autoconfigure: false
```